# What is wrong with this code..(Animating the view up)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, uikeyboard

I am not sure why is this happening..

I am trying to animate my view up when the user starts typing in a text field. but the code works only for landscape left orientation but not landscape right...

these methods are called in both orientation...

here is the code..

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    if ( keyboardShown )
        return;

        NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.3;
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.size.width += 150;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
        self.view.frame = frame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];



    keyboardShown = YES;
}

- (void)keyboardWasHidden:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

        NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.3;
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.size.width -= 150;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
        self.view.frame = frame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];


    keyboardShown = NO;
}
```

as of now I have just hardcoded the values..

Comment: Have you returned yes in - "(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation" ?? or is this your root view controller that you have added to the window??

Comment: Why are you adjusting the width instead of the height?

Comment: Yes you should adjust the height...

Comment: I have added this view controller to the root view controller and the height is coming as 1024 where as width is  coming out as 748... ? Animation doesn't make sense to me.. :P

Comment: ok but it will not be the same in landscape orientation..there you will need to implement this code

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper I didn't get you..

Comment: in landscape orientation your height will be 768..so there you will need to shift up the view using this code..

Comment: that's what I am doing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK ..  figured it out with some help...

When you set the frame of a view and its controller is added to the window's root view controller then you should use bounds....

because the windows frame remains constant...

so here is how the new code looks..

```
- (void)keyboardShown:(NSNotification *) aNotification {
    if ( keyboardShown )
        return;
    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    frame.origin.y += 150;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    self.view.bounds = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    keyboardShown = NO;
}

- (void)keyboardHidden:(NSNotification *) aNotification {
    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    frame.origin.y -= 150;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    self.view.bounds = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    keyboardShown = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you animate the origin of your view instead of the size?

```
frame.origin.y -= 150;
```

and

```
frame.origin.y = 0;
```

Comment: This even though makes sense but makes my view shift left in landscape left orientation and right in landscape right orientation... and if I change the  x value of origin then it moves up for one and down for the other.. :/

Comment: you could do view.center.y -= 150;

Comment: Sorry man even this doesn't work out.. same problem as above... Something else is wrong , something with setting the root view controller , thanks for your efforts